# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama when compiling window manager

Tags: rust

When I'm trying to compile https://github.com/Kintaro/wtftw or code from tutorial https://kintaro.github.io/rust/window-manager-in-rust-01/ written by the same author, I get an error message that says

`note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama`
 The problem seems to be in this crate

`extern crate xinerama;`

But xinerama itself builds successfully.
How can I change code/cargo settings or anything else to fix it? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and rust nightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to install libxinerama and libxinerama-dev

Comment: Thanks! The problem was in libxinerama-dev.